# Shell script with input in docker container

Tags: docker, shell

I have a .sh script (`server-setup.sh`) running in a docker container asking a question and waiting for the user to write something in the console. I use the `read` function which writes the user input to a variable and then some "if" which does something based on the user input.

When the container starts, it calls the `entrypoint.sh` that calls immediately the `server-setup.sh`. The script starts, but something is entering an empty input, so the script exits.

`server-setup.sh`

```sh
    echo "Select server type\n "
    echo " 1) Vanilla\n 2) Paper\n 3) Forge\n 4) Mohist\n 5) Quit"
    read server_type_num
    if [ "$server_type_num" = "1" ]; then
      server_type="Vanilla"
      server_ver_select
    elif [ "$server_type_num" = "2" ]; then
      server_type="PaperMC"
      server_ver_select
    elif [ "$server_type_num" = "3" ]; then
      server_type="Forge"
      #server_ver_select
      echo "Working on..."
    elif [ "$server_type_num" = "4" ]; then
      server_type="Mohist"
      #server_ver_select
      echo "Working on..."
    elif [ "$server_type_num" = "5" ]; then
      echo "Bye!"
      return
    else
      echo "Invalid option"
      echo "Option: $server_type_num"
      return
    fi
```

Result:

```sh
    Select server type
     1) Vanilla
     2) Paper
     3) Forge
     4) Mohist
     5) Quit
    Invalid option
    Option:
```

Versions:

```
Docker version: 20.10.6

Docker is running on: Ubuntu Server (Focal 20.04 LTS)

Container image: Ubuntu
```

Comment: How are you launching the container?  (Do you have a `docker run -i` option?)  Also consider passing this setting as an environment variable, or depending on how you use it as the container command, rather than requiring interactive input like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is not a good practice to have an interactive entrypoint in a `Dockerfile`, the reason you are not being prompted for an input is because docker does not run in an interactive mode, unless you request it with the `-it` flags.

```
$ docker run --help
  # ...
  -t, --tty           Allocate a pseudo-TTY
  -i, --interactive   Keep STDIN open even if not attached
```

So, you can run:

```
$ docker run --rm -it your_image ...
```

A better option would be to use an environment variable. For example:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh
server_ver_select() {
  echo "Server is $server_type"
}

server_type="${SERVER_TYPE:-Vanilla}"
server_ver_select
```

And run with:

```
$ docker run --rm -it -e SERVER_TYPE=PaperMC temp
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked fine, but i want to run this image with a software (Pterodactyl, a game server management panel) and I prefer to use the interactive option. Thanks again.